# Proper setup for visual studio and SVN

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, svn, version-control

I am wanting to setup a project and potentially an existing project to be SVN version controlled. I am using uberSVN for the svn server. I have installed AnkhSVN for visual studio.

Currently, the team I am working with is using visual source safe and one of the problems we have is when someone adds a reference to a DLL, it modifies the project file as you would expect, but our paths are different between different team members (XP boxes, 7, you get the idea). What I was wanting is making the project file ignored when checking in/out so that we don't mess up the references for everyone else.

Is there a way I can make SVN ignore these files within the plugin? One of the side effects of this is a person would not know if a new file has been added in the project as this modifies the project file. Other than telling everyone "hey, you need to manually add this file to your project," is there a cleaner way of doing it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should start using virtual paths for development work; that way each team member can keep work-related files at any physical location but the virtual path (the one seen by tools is always the same.

For example, my team does all work under `Q:\`. My physical source for work is under physical path `C:\Work\<project_name>` where the project_name part depends on the project. When I want to work on a given project, I map the Q:\ virtual path to the right physical path using

```
subst q: c:\work\project_name
```

When I need to switch, I run a similar command. This way there's no need to worry about different paths on different computers. This worked very well for the whole team and eliminated most issues you describe above. The only thing you need to make sure is that everyone always uses the virtual path (Q:), not the physical path when dealing with project-related files. For my team it took about a week to get used to that, after that there were no more problems.

Your project file is an important part of your project so ignoring it in the source control tool will eventually lead to problems. I recommend you don't do it (even if you can).

**Edit**:
If you have DLL-s in different physical folders on different machines, the best choice is to copy those DLL-s (and their dependencies) to a known location. It's fine that they can't run from there, as long as the compiler finds them.

This known location could be inside your virtual path or a common physical path (if the same DLL-s are needed for multiple projects). You can use [Dependency Walker](http://www.dependencywalker.com/) to determine what dependencies you need for native DLL-s and [Reflector](http://www.reflector.net) for .NET DLL-s.

If the size/number of DLL-s is so large that creating a copy is not an option, you can actually tell AnkhSVN to ignore certain versioned files when committing changes. Right-click the file, select Subversion > Move to Change List > ignore-on-commit. After this the file will show up in the commit dialog unselected but you can still commit it if you manually select it.

Comment: This doesn't quite work because of our window box people pointing to Program Files(x86) and our XP people pointing to Program Files for certain DLLs.

Comment: @Justin: I updated my answer - you can either copy your DLL-s to a known location or you can tell AnkhSVN to show certain files unchecked when committing changes.

Answer (score 4):

If you copy the DLL to a folder inside your VS solution folder before linking to it, I think the project link will be relative not absolute. So you can check the DLL and the updated VS project into your configuration management and everyone should be able to share it.

Comment: We do this too ... works very well. Completely indepent to what folders developers use.